# Using Atata Framework , Can we do database operations like connecting to database and checking the records in table?

Tags: atata

Using Atata framework, can we connect to database and perform database operations?

I was not able to find any template related to database in atata framework tutorial.

I know that we can connect to database using Selenium drivers.Just wanted to know whether it is possible through atata.

```
public static int DBTest(IWebDriver session, string connString)
{
  var DBConnection = new SqlConnection(connString);
  DBConnection.Open();
}
```

No reference for database conn in atata found.please help

Answer (score 2):

Atata framework doesn't contain any DB related functionality, because it should NOT, as well as other testing libraries don't have it, like Selenium WebDriver, Appium, NUnit, XUnit, etc. Operating with DB should be a separate thing out of Atata, but be a part of your testing solution.

For C#/.NET there are great libraries for DB actions: ADO.NET, Entity Framework, Dapper, etc. You can use any of these with Atata, NUnit, doesn't matter.

Comment: Hi Sir,

Thanks for your answer. But I am looking out for a automated framework like atata which can test the database results for a .net Developer. I mean to say ,  I am trying to lookout for a framework which can tell me whether the database query/sp is returning the expected results or not.